# tcpdump/tshark: view only outgoing TCP connections requests

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I would like to view `TCP` requests (syn packets) initiated by my PC/server to other hosts. More specifically, I would like to view the `outgoing connection requests`. How can I accomplish this?

Also, I don't want to see any connection attempts that are coming to my PC/server.

The following `iptables` command works but it's clunky to use as it logs everything while I just want to see everything on the screen:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j LOG
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to see outgoing TCP connections originating from your host you can use the switch `src host <ip>` as an argument to `tcpdump`:

```
$ tcpdump -i any -nn src host 10.0.2.15 and port 80
```

#### Example

Simulated outgoing traffic:

```
$ curl -vv telnet://www.google.com:80
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 172.217.15.100...
* Connected to www.google.com (172.217.15.100) port 80 (#0)
^C
```

Watching with `tcpdump`:

```
$ tcpdump -i any -nn src host 10.0.2.15 and port 80
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
11:04:19.585773 IP 10.0.2.15.50642 > 216.58.218.4.80: Flags [S], seq 315169574, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 38358006 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:04:19.623676 IP 10.0.2.15.50642 > 216.58.218.4.80: Flags [.], ack 470600706, win 29200, length 0
```

#### Filtering on syn packets

To capture just the outgoing syn packets you'll need to analyze the tcpflags, specifically looking for the `tcp-syn` flag. Again using the same `curl` command from above, but now invoking `tcpdump` like so:

```
$ tcpdump -i any -nn src host 10.0.2.15 and "tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-syn"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
11:13:39.962475 IP 10.0.2.15.44810 > 64.233.185.103.80: Flags [S], seq 3710429425, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 38918382 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

#### tcpflags

From the `tcpdump` man page:

> ```
> The general format of a TCP protocol line is:
>
> src > dst: Flags [tcpflags], seq data-seqno, ack ackno, win window, urg urgent, options [opts], length len
>
> Src and dst are the source and destination IP addresses and ports. 
> Tcpflags are some combination of S (SYN), F (FIN), P (PUSH), R (RST), U 
> (URG), W (ECN CWR), E (ECN-Echo) or `.' (ACK), or `none' if no flags are 
> set. Data-seqno describes the portion of sequence space covered by the 
> data in this packet (see example below). Ackno is sequence number of the 
> next data expected the other direction on this connection. Window is the 
> number of bytes of receive buffer space available the other direction on 
> this connection. Urg indicates there is `urgent' data in the packet. Opts 
> are TCP options (e.g., mss 1024). Len is the length of payload data.
> ```

#### References

- [A tcpdump Tutorial and Primer with Examples](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/)
- [How to capture ack or syn packets by Tcpdump?](https://serverfault.com/questions/217605/how-to-capture-ack-or-syn-packets-by-tcpdump)
- [slmingol/tcp_flags.txt](https://gist.github.com/slmingol/ceefd4f49840b3302e055886d679456d)
- [Amit's notes - Docs » Networking » tcpdump](https://amits-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/networking/tcpdump.html)